# capistrano deployment unable to bundle install gem with no internet connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am deploying my application to a new server which has everything installed.

I am using the following capistrano deploy.rb:

```
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :default_environment, {
    'ORACLE_HOME' => "/opt/oraclient/64/11.2.0.2/",
    'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' => "$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/usr/local/lib",
    'PATH' => "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin"
}

SECURE_FILES = ['database.yml', 'ldap.yml', 'initializers/secret_token.rb']

set :application,   "myapp"
set :use_sudo,      false

set :scm,           :git
set :repository, "ssh://git@hostname:7999/web/myapp.git"
set :user, "webuser"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

after "deploy:update_code", "custom:create_symlinks", "custom:assets_precompile", "custom:miscellaneous"
after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Restarting mod_rails with restart.txt"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  [:start, :stop].each do |t|
    desc "#{t} task is a no-op with mod_rails"
    task t, :roles => :app do ; end
  end

  namespace :web do
    desc "Enable maintenance mode for apache"
    task :enable_maintenance, :role => :web do

      run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/system"
      on_rollback { run "rm -f #{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html" }
      page = File.read('public/maintenance.html')
      put page, "#{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html", :mode => 0644
    end

    desc "Disable maintenance mode for apache"
    task :disable_maintenance, :role => :web do
      run "rm -f #{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html"
    end
  end
end

namespace :custom do
  desc "Creating config, bundler-GEMS symlinks"
  task :create_symlinks, :roles => :app do

    #Secure Configuration File Symlinks 
    SECURE_FILES.each do |link|
      fobj = "#{release_path}/config/#{link}"
      run <<-CMD
        if [ -e #{fobj} ]; then rm -f #{fobj}; fi;
        rm -f #{previous_release}/config/#{fobj};
        ln -s #{vormetric_path}/#{application}/#{link} #{fobj};
      CMD
    end

    #Bundler GEM Installation Symlink 
    shared_bundler_dir = File.join(shared_path, 'bundle')
    release_bundler_dir = File.join(current_release, 'vendor/bundle')
    run "ln -s #{shared_bundler_dir} #{release_bundler_dir}"
  end

  desc "Assets Pre-Compilation"
  task :assets_precompile, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_release} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  end

  desc "Miscellaneous Tasks"
  task :miscellaneous, :roles => :app do
    run "chmod -f +w #{current_release}/db/schema.rb"
  end
end
```

This is box-specific deploy script myhostname.rb:

server "myhostname", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

```
set :deploy_to, "/opt/web/var/myapp"
set :rails_env, "customertest"
set :branch, "staging"
```

Now the remote box does not have access to internet, but I have all my gems stored under vendor/cache. So it should pick up from there.(vendor/cache has nokigiri under /myapp/current/vendor/cache on remote server)

When i run

> cap deploy servername

, i get the following error:

```
 ** [out :: myhost] An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.9), and Bundler cannot
 ** [out :: myhost] continue.
 ** [out :: myhost] Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My remote box where the code is supposed to be deployed has the following folders set up:

```
 /opt/web/var/myapp
 /opt/web/var/myapp/current(where all the code is cloned currently)
 /opt/web/var/myapp/releases
 /opt/web/var/myapp/shared
```

I am not sure how it i supposed to pick up and install the gem.

Comment: There should be much more to the error than just those three lines. Can you please show us the full error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quote from bundler docs might be relevant (emphasis mine):

http://bundler.io/v1.9/bundle_package.html

> By default, if you simply run bundle install after running bundle package, Bundler **will still connect to rubygems.org** to check whether a **platform-specific gem** exists for any of the gems in vendor/cache.
>   This behavior can be avoided by instead running **bundle install --local**. Note that this requires you to have the correctly platformed version for all of your gems already cached. The easiest way to achieve this is to run bundle package on an identical machine and then check in those vendored gems.

So, in short, you need to pass the **--local** flag when running bundler in the production server to avoid connecting to rubygems altogether.

The solution for use with `capistrano` is to set this variable in you `deploy.rb` file:

```
# deployment and quiet are used by default, we add the local flag
set :bundle_flags, "--deployment --quiet --local"
```